# Append dynamic object to Array list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this sample object which is actually dynamic:

```
const foo = { "userId":"250","80":"0","81":"1"};
```

I want to append dynamically as i expected result below but for now it is just for showing

```
const reqObj = {arrList:[{ "userId":"250","qId":"80","anId":"0"},{"userId":"250","qId":"81","anId":"1"}]}
```

Comment: I see neither Angular nor Typescript here. How do you append? Show more code

Comment: This is just piece of code that I'm working in angular

Comment: var reqObj = {arrList:[]};

    var foo = { "userId":"250","80":"0","81":"1"}
    reqObj.arrList.push(foo);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const foo = { userId: "250", "80": "0", "81": "1" };

const { userId, ...rest } = foo;

const reqObj = {
  arrList: Object.keys(rest).map((key) => ({
    userId,
    qId: key,
    anId: rest[key],
  })),
};

console.log(reqObj);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```